# argument of type WORD* is incompatible with parameter of type LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, lpcwstr

The problem is `&cursorTile.Attributes.`
The error I am getting is `(argument of type "WORD*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR")`
I have tried to find some solutions, I am using multi-byte character set.

```
void CMap::Draw(){
SMALL_RECT drawRect = { 0, 0, MAP_WIDTH - 1, MAP_HEIGHT - 1 };
COORD buffersize = { MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT };
COORD zeroZero = { 0, 0 };
DWORD dwResult = 0;
char szCursor[2] = "";

HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

for (int i = 0; i < (int)m_vTiles.size(); i++){
    m_screenBuffer[i] = m_vTiles[i].GetChar();
}

WriteConsoleOutput(hOutput, m_screenBuffer, buffersize, zeroZero, &drawRect);

if (g_pCursorTile != NULL){
    CHAR_INFO cursorTile = g_pCursorTile->GetChar();
    sprintf(szCursor, "%c", cursorTile.Char);
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hOutput, szCursor, 1, g_cursorPos, &dwResult);
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hOutput, &cursorTile.Attributes, 1, g_cursorPos, &dwResult);
}
```

Comment: Is it `WORD` or `DWORD`?

Comment: The error says it is WORD*

Comment: Your second call to WriteConsoleOutputCharacter should be a call to WriteConsoleOutputAttribute.

Comment: OMG! that fixed it!! :| didnt see i did that. Thx man

Answer (score 1):

this is very explenetory error. 
`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` expects some string as the second argument. if your program is defined as unicode, it expects `LPCWSTR`, which is basically an (ugly) type-definition to a null terminated `wchar_t*` string.

in your invocation, you pass `&cursorTile.Attributes` which has the type of `DWORD*` (which is again, ugly type-definition to `unsigned long*`). you need to pass some wide-char string instead of unsigned long pointer, which is , the string you are trying to print.

Comment: What i dont understand is cursorTile is of type CHAR_INFO not DWORD. dwResult is of type DWORD

Comment: yes but it complains on something completly different. read my answer.

Comment: k so what i understand is that im am using 2 types of strings?? and writeconsoleoutputcharacter wants me to use one, which is related to LPCWSTR. sry if i sound dum im still learning c++

Comment: we both agree that writeconsoleoutputcharacter prints a string?

Comment: yea writeconsoleoutputcharacter needs to print a string to the screen.

Comment: so this string should be the seconf argument of writeconsoleoutputcharacter .

Comment: I found the mistake it was the writeconsoleoutputcharacter it self. i should have writen writeconsoleoutputattributes xD thx to roger lipscombe

Answer (score 0):

> DWORD:     A 32-bit unsigned integer. The range is 0 through 4294967295
>   decimal.

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
```

> LPCWSTR:   A pointer to a constant null-terminated string of 16-bit
>   Unicode characters.

```
typedef CONST WCHAR *LPCWSTR;
```

Both are different datatypes altogether.